Compiling three columns off of ten sheet into ten columns on one summary
I am trying to put together a schedule in Excel for a work project. (yes, there are better ways to do this, but I was told use Excel and I want to avoid doing it manually)
We have 10 people, each manually changing the cell colours in their own sheet of three columns, Jan, Feb and March. Then we want a summary sheet that automatically picks up the colours they picked organized by person.
The musts are: each person has their own sheet and the colours are changed manually. I can reorganize how the columns are adjusted, but the easier it is organizationally for those people, the better.
Here's what I got so far:
Dim s As Integer

For s = 1 To 99 
Sheet1.Range("A" + s) = Sheet2.Range("A" + s) 
Next

And repeat ten times.
My problem is, if they're colouring their personal sheet in three columns but the summary sheet is one column, s doesn't work as a variable.
Adding an if s < whatever then such and such statements have not been cooperating with me as my VBA knowledge is pretty basic.
How do I make three colours colour in one column? I hope that explanation made any sense.

For each sh in Worksheets, finding the currentSheetLastRow in each, and appending currentSheetLastRow = currentSheetLastRow+1 within your smaller loop would allow you to have a sheet-specific variable while maintaining your source-sheet s.  I would recommend using plain-English variables so when you look back, it's easier to decipher.

You can't put three colors as the fill in a cell. Excel simply doesn't allow it.  You could use shapes to handle this:
Sub AddShapes(Color1 As Long, Color2 As Long, Color3 As Long, nLeft1 As Long, nTop1 As Long, nLeft2 As Long, nTop2 As Long, nLeft3 As Long, nTop3 As Long, nWidth As Long, nHeight As Long)
Dim Sh As Shape
Dim wksh As Worksheet
        
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set Sh = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, nLeft1, nTop1, nWidth, nHeight)
        Sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color1
        Set Sh = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, nLeft2, nTop2, nWidth, nHeight)
        Sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color2
        Set Sh = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, nLeft3, nTop3, nWidth, nHeight)
        Sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color3
    End With

End Sub

As you iterate through your individual sheets and cells, you get the fill colors for each cell to assign to a shape, then assign the location in the destination sheet (change "Sheet1" to the destination sheet name) using its Top and Left position and the size of the shapes.  The only twitchy part of this is setting the Top and Left values to match the cells in the destination sheet.
